# Isotope wont start - get undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm getting an error
[image]

here is my code:

```
    var $container = $('#companyContainer').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.companyRow',
            layoutMode: 'masonry',
            getSortData: {
              data1: function(item) {
                        return parseInt($(item).attr('data1'));
                    },
              data2:  function(item) {
                        return parseInt($(item).attr('data2'));
                    }
            }
    });
```

I also have the isotope loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/isotope.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you loading the isotope file before that script block runs? Or is that script block contained inside a document.ready function?

Comment: yes, i load jquery, then isotope, some other scripts and then scrpts.js (that has the code block above)

Comment: What versions of Jquery and Isotope?

Comment: here is the jquery: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: and its:  Isotope v1.4.110721

Comment: Actually, I upgraded to isotope's v2 and that seemed to work